# Javascript Variable Scope with KendoUI Components

Tags: javascript, scope, kendo-ui

I am trying to capture the text from a Kendo AutoComplete component and save it to a variable to later use in other components. The code is below and I have a link to the code at [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/agopuz/10/edit). Note: the code jsbin.com does not work for me in IE9, Firefox and Chrome work fine.

I attach my onSelect function fires when a selecton is made in the autoComplete control. I then assign the dataItem to my variable "selectedGeoname". I successfully write the object's text property to an element on screen and I use an alert to confirm that selectedGeoname is populated by the object.

However, when I later try to use the variable to pass the value to another component, the variable is null. I instantiate both components and declare the variable inside $(document)ready. I would have to believe that this is all ablout scope so perhaps one of you javascript wizards can help poor old .Net guy to fix this code.

Thanks,

Greg

```
HTML as follows:

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>  
  <head>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.common.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.default.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>
      <label for="customer">Choose a customer:</label>
      <input id="customer" />
      <div id="result"></div>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="stores">Choose a store:</label>
      <input id="stores" />
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#customer").kendoAutoComplete({
          dataTextField: "name",
          dataSource: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
              read: {
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                  featureClass: "P",
                  style: "full",
                  maxRows: 12,
                  name_startsWith: function () {
                    return $("#customer").val();
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            schema: {
              data: "geonames"
            }
          },
          filter: "startswith",
          placeholder: "Select Customer...",
          height: 500,
          suggest: true,
          select: onSelect
        });

        var selectedGeoname;

        function onSelect(e) {
          var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
          selectedGeoname = dataItem;

          //output
          $("#result").html(selectedGeoname.name);
          alert(selectedGeoname);
        }

        $("#stores").kendoDropDownList({
          autoBind: false,
          enable: true,
          dataTextField: "StoreName",
          dataValueField: "StoreId",
          dataSource: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
              read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("JsonGetStores", "Home")',
                data: {
                  customer: selectedGeoname
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code as your onSelect to achieve this:

```
    function onSelect(e) {

        selectedGeoname = this.value();

      //output
        $("#result").html(selectedGeoname.name);
        alert(selectedGeoname);
    }
```

When called from the context of the AutoComplete object `this.value()` can be used to get the value of the AC input element.

If you need to access the current value of the variable outside of the scope you can use this method:  `$("#customer").data("kendoAutoComplete").value()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well I was unable to get this.value() to even compile, in VS or in jsbin. However, when I changed the scope of the variable, moving it outside the ready(), I am able to display the selected text on screen as the $("result") div and in the alert; by assigning it the result of dataItem.name.

Comment: The really annoying issue is that this works only in jsbin and not in my C# razor page.

Comment: You can use this: `$("#customer").data("kendoAutoComplete").value()`. to get the value of the box outside the scope. (had some problems with it when debugging in jsbin, but should work fine in production). Ive updated my answer as well.

Comment: Yes, using a function I am able to pass the text value of the Kendo AutoComplete into a DropDownList.

function getData() {
  var data = $("#customer").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
  return data;
}

Thanks Logard, very much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, only happy to help. I think kendo is a quite good framework, so I try to out if people have problems :) It can be a bit tricky at times.